# Create a file in a directory shell

Tags: shell

I have a directory named "dir" in which there is an html file and folders named 01 02 03 ... 10. I want to create from the folder "dir", in each folder a file page01.html for the folder 01 and page02.html for the dir 02 etc ..

I have tried:

```
for i in `ls -a * /`; do
touch page$i.html
done
```

But it does not create me files in directories.

thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To create a file `pageX.html` for each directory `X`, you can use:

```
for dir in */
do
  touch "$dir/page$dir.html"
done
```

This is the safer and less redundant version of `` for dir in `ls -d */` ``, which should never be used as it has problems with various types of special characters.

If you have other directories, you can limit it to ones with two digits as the name:

```
for dir in [0-9][0-9]/
do
  touch "$dir/page$dir.html"
done
```

Comment: I appreciate your answer especially the second part, it will help me. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
for d in {01..10}; do
   touch "$d/page$d.html"
done
```

Comment: the brace expansion `{01..10}` also works, and respects the leading zero.

Comment: @Digger: Glad to know it worked out, you may mark the answer as accepted by clicking on tick mark on top-left of my answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
/tmp/dir> ls -d *
01  02  03  04  05  06  07  08  09  10
/tmp/dir> for d in `ls -d *`; do f=$d/page$d.html ; touch $f; ls $f; done
01/page01.html
02/page02.html
03/page03.html
04/page04.html
05/page05.html
06/page06.html
07/page07.html
08/page08.html
09/page09.html
10/page10.html
/tmp/dir>
```